# Canvas game only starts drawing when the window is inactive

Tags: javascript, canvas

I noticed something weird in my canvas code: Im making a game with little flying ghosts. The class for the ghost is below. When I just draw 1 or 2 of em by manually adding the code and having em fly to the right by updating the x every frame for example everything runs smoothly and fine.

Now I ran another test and added a ghost every 100 frames to an array, update its x by 100  and then draw that ghost to the frame. (code is below the first block, the draw function).

**Now the problem is that they are actually added and drawn, but I dont see em on the board until I make the window inactive by clicking on the taskbar for example.**

Any1 got a clue what is going wrong here?

```
    /* 
 * Class for little ghosts
 */
function Ghost (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ghost = new Image();
    this.ghost.src = "img/ghost.png";
    this.ghostWidth = 150;
    this.ghostHeight = 100;
    this.ghostSpriteOffsetX = 0;
    this.ghostSpriteOffsetY = 0;
    this.ghostX = 0;
    this.ghostY = 0;
}
Ghost.prototype.drawGhost = function() {
    context2D.drawImage(this.ghost, this.ghostSpriteOffsetX, this.ghostSpriteOffsetY, this.ghostWidth, this.ghostHeight, this.ghostX, this.ghostY, this.ghostWidth, this.ghostHeight);
};
Ghost.prototype.goToX = function(x) {
    this.ghostX = x;
};
Ghost.prototype.goToY = function(y) {
    this.ghostY = y;
};
Ghost.prototype.turnPink = function() {
    this.ghostSpriteOffsetX = 0;
};
Ghost.prototype.turnBlue = function() {
    this.ghostSpriteOffsetX = 150;
};
Ghost.prototype.turnPurple = function() {
    this.ghostSpriteOffsetX = 300;
 };
```

-

```
function draw()
{
// clear board
context2D.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

if(frame%100==0){
    ghosts[ghostId] = new Ghost("g-"+frame);
    ghosts[ghostId].goToX(frame-100);
    ghostId++;
}
// Draw ghost
for (i=0; i<ghosts.length; i++)
{
    ghosts[i].drawGhost();
}



frame++;
}
```

Comment: How do you call your drawing routines? With setTimeout? I.e.: Do they end between the different frames or is it a big while-loop?

Comment: Using `setInterval(draw, 1000 / FPS);`

Comment: Hm, this doesn't match my theory. (The canvas will only refresh when the script is finished.) Did you test if this error is browser specific?

Comment: It is browser specific I just noticed. This only happens in Firefox, and only in approx 70% of the time.... Hmmpf... Maybe I should try prerendering?

Comment: I am more into the Opera Browser, sorry. I suggest to modify different things in order to check if it changes something (CSS, DOM-structure, calling of the script, order of load events (maybe race condition?)).

Comment: It's possible the draw routine is taking longer than the interval, which might give odd behaivor... Have you tried using either `requestAnimationFrame` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame)) or `setTimeout(draw, 1000/FPS)` at the end of the draw fnc?